# How to make div color appear in front of another?

Tags: html, css

I want to know what is the wrong with following code; I want to make the inner div color appear as a part of the outer div color. I am using this for a percentage poll bar:

```
echo '<div style="width:130px; height:20px; background-color:#ecf2f9; overflow:hidden;">';

    echo '<div style="width:<?php print $percent1; ?>%; background-color:#ff33cc; position:relative; z-index:3"></div>';

    echo '</div>';
```

or if there will be another solution to get the result i need.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what is the value of $percent1 ???

Comment: `echo '...<?php ...` you need to look at how php work, copy and past is not the answer...

Comment: it depends on how many votes this option got form the total votes. But anyway it is not zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is relatively simple. Just set the hight for the inner div and you are done ;)

A DIV has no default height. That's the problem.

**Example:**

```
echo '<div style="width:130px;  background-color:#ecf2f9;">';
echo '<div style="width:<?php print $percent1; ?>%; background-color:#ff33cc;  height:20px;"></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

You can see a plain HTML example of your bar here:
https://jsfiddle.net/eaz1vbex/

Beside that, using `<?php print $percent1; ?>` that way won't work, because echo outputs the content without further parsing by the PHP interpreter. If you want to keep the above style of code, you should change it to the following before continue reading:

```
echo '<div style="width:130px;  background-color:#ecf2f9;">';
echo '<div style="width:' . $percent1 . '%; background-color:#ff33cc;  height:20px;"></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Alternatively:

```
echo "<div style='width:130px;  background-color:#ecf2f9;'>";
echo "<div style='width:$percent1%; background-color:#ff33cc;  height:20px;'></div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Please read this for better understanding:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Hints:

- You should use CSS for all style attributes (except width, which is dynamic). Using the style tag is not recommended because it makes it hard to maintain and redesign later in the product lifecycle. It also bloats up output.
- You maybe want to use some sort of template engine or at least the "here document"-syntax, for better maintainability of markup.

**Example:**

```
echo <<<END
    <div style="width:130px;  background-color:#ecf2f9;">
        <div style="width:$percent1%; background-color:#ff33cc;  height:20px;"></div>
    </div>
END;
```

**Example with seperate CSS:**

CSS:

```
 .progressBar { width:130px; background-color: #ecf2f9; }
 .progressBar .progress { background-color:#FF33cc; height: 20px; }
```

PHP:

```
echo <<<END
    <div class="progressBar">
        <div style="width:$percent1%;" class="progress"></div>
    </div>
END;
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/fchp5aqa/

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works now. Really appreciated

Comment: @Roko: Yes, your right, that obviously cannot work as intended. Beside that the code of the OP in general isn't good practice practice. Anyway that wasn't the question. If you pick the last example i've added, it will work. I wall add an update to the answer just to avoid irritations.

Answer (score 0):

it's work : i have set a `height : 20px` and your `$percent1` did not print !! so i change it and fix it. i think it enough to understand what i done!!

```
    echo '<div style="width:130px; height:20px; background-color:red;   overflow:hidden;">';

echo '<div style="width:'.$percent1.'%; background-color:blue; position:relative; z-index:3; height:20px;"></div>';

echo '</div>';
```